# Remove Shared with and Design manager options- SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to remove the Shared with and Design manager options from SharePoint menu by manipulating permission.

But I could not find the relevant permission level. Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you're after: https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2016/04/changing-or-removing-the-seemingly-unchangeable-options-in-sharepoint-online-office-365-site-actions/

Looks like it's just a case of inserting your own custom CSS to modify it's appearance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to limit the results, you can limit the results in the peoplepicker by  : *"stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "OU=Bla,OU=Bla,DC=Bla,DC=com" -url "url to site"*